# AngluarJS Checkbox becoming unchecked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a scenario where I load the page with a check box already checked. In the load of the controller I make a call to a web api to load the content of the web api call into a table.

The problem is, after the web api call happens, I loose the fact that my check box is checked. I am not sure what the problem is. I created a small example of it in a plunk, and it happens there.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/J82bvl338fdtKLkW5reu?p=info

```
      var Url = "https://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query=90210";
  self.$http.get(Url, this.requestConfig).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('success', data);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
    console.log('error', data);
  });
```

What should happen is the check box remain checked after the http get happens.

I am using the controller as syntax, and am wondering if I am missing something in this scenario...

Answer (score 1):

In the html file when you init the chk member you are using this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk" ng-model="chk" ng-init="chk = 'true'" checked/>
```

You are using single quotes for the `true` value. Remove them and you should be fine:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk" ng-model="chk" ng-init="chk = true" checked/>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, i wish I would have gotten a console note from angular

Comment: @JasonZimmer Yes I know, those kind of errors are hard to spot, maybe it would be better to initialize your members in the controller instead of inline and that makes it a little bit easier, not perfect but better to debug at leat